# Can I use construction adhesive to mount a 4' LED Shop light on a Flexicore ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, led, adhesive

I am about to move in a a new (to me) condo with a [Flexicore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexicore) (precast concrete panel) ceiling.  I am not sure if I can drill into the ceiling or not so I am looking for alternate way to hang a 4' LED shop light in a closet.

Ignoring any electrical connections, as I can deal with that part of it, would it be possible to use construction adhesive to mount a 4' LED shop light to the Flexicore ceiling?  Would it have enough strength to hold up that light?  If not any other suggestions?

Comment: I would not rely on adhesive for this application. If it fails, it could cause pretty serious injury (including electrocution) to someone, and IMHO it's just not worth the risk. I'd look to build something from a wall, depending on the span and distance to walls you could potential have a metal or wood beam running wall-to-wall, or a couple large angle/shelf brackets.

Comment: OK, i will have to check it out more once I close on the space, until then I am just exploring options in my mind.

Comment: How far from the wall(s) does the light need to be?

Comment: It is a walk in type closet, but it isn't very wide, or very big, it is pretty long though.  Until I close on the place and can get in I won't really know what I can and can't do or dimensions.

Comment: In general, don't use adhesive for anything you might want to disassemble nondestructively for service...

Comment: So I finally moved in to the new place and was able to do this. I was able to drill in to the ceiling and mount the light, I did not have to do anything out of the ordinary, thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use adhesive to mount a LED fixture. The LED fixtures I use have large heat sinks on the top of the fixture to dissipate the heat generated. Gluing the fixture could cause 2 problems:

1. The glue would not allow free airflow on the top of the fixture causing a higher temperature than the LEDs are rated for and this could severely reduce their life.
2. How to remove a dead glued to the ceiling fixture.

I guess there could be A 3rd reason what to do when my closet catches fire from a fixture that was not installed per the listing instructions ( ok this one is a stretch because the drivers usually shut down when they overheat).

I would check into flexcore and see the mounting methods available.

Comment: The third reason is that it probably will not hold.

Comment: I know how I can properly mount to flexicore, by drilling in to it and putting in the proper anchors.  But the biggest hold-up against that is if the condo board will let me do that or not.  They could maintain that I could cause problems with structural integrity so they may not let me do it.  I'll see what I can do and go from there, seems like the adhesive is off the table though.  I might be able to do something with the walls and wood to create a mounting point for myself that way.  Have to see what I can do once I get in.  Thanks for all the feedback, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is my universal solution to that, usually with West System epoxy with the fillers intended for gluing etc...

1. Glue a piece of plywood to the surface.
2. Mount the component to that.

The problem with gluing components directly, aside from the component failing... Is that you have *no idea* how well the glue will adhere to the component. Some of them are quite bad.  In any case, the components are not listed for mounting with glue, which makes it illegal to do so.